# Python: Printing a list with a line break after every nth item

Tags: python-3.x, printing, list-comprehension, line-breaks

I have a list of media that I want to print in the following format, with a line break after every nth item:

```
media_list = ['A001', 'A002', 'A003', 'A004', 'A005', 'A006', 'A007', 'A008']
```

> A001  OR
>   A002    OR
>   A003    OR
>   A004    OR
>   
>   A005    OR
>   A006    OR
>   A007    OR
>   A008    OR

But I'm not sure how to create the line break. This is what I have so far:
(I was thinking of using the gaps tuple in a list comprehension somehow...)

```
print('\n'.join('{}\tOR'.format(m) for m in media_list))
gaps = tuple(range(0, len(media_list), 4))[:0:-1]
```

In reality the list will include hundreds of entries and the line break will need to be after every 30th.
First python script, help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it is what you want. Hope it helps :)

```
media_list = [
    'A00{}'.format(i) for i in range (1,10)
]

nth_item = 4

str_list = [
    '{}\tOR\n'.format(m)
    if(((media_list.index(m)+1) % nth_item) == 0)
    else
    '{}\tOR'.format(m)
    for m in media_list
]

print('\n'.join(str_list))
```

Comment: Or using `enumerate` in a generator expression, without using `str.join`:  `print(*(('{}\tOR' if i % nth_item else '{}\tOR\n').format(m) for i, m in enumerate(media_list, 1)), sep='\n')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
for i, e in enumerate(my_list, n_elements):
    print(e)
```

Replace my_list with your list name and n_elements with the number of elements after which you want the line break.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert line break every `n`th line by printing element of the list `['', '\n']` accessed by index `i % n == 0`, where `i` is current item number:

```
n = 4

for i, e in enumerate(media_list, 1):
    print(e, ' OR', ['', '\n'][i % n == 0], sep='')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34599974)